# date formatting using nsdate formatter

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting data in following format

```
20130224233000 where,

2013 - year
02 month 
24 day

23 hh 
30 mm
00 ss
```

and I want in following format

```
Wednesday, 24-Feb-13  11:30 PM
```

I tried as below code

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
return dateString;
```

but it give a format which I don"t required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two NSDateFormatters, one to convert to NSDate and the other to NSString. Use the [format table](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) as reference.

```
NSString* date = @"20130224233000";
NSDateFormatter *parser = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[parser setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"eeee, dd-MMM-yy hh:mm a"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[parser dateFromString:date]];
return dateString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE d-MMM-yy HH:mma"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
return dateString;
```

Comment: but i want to convert 20130224233000 to Wednesday, 24-Feb-13  11:30 PM not a NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

Comment: What is the type of 20130224233000? `NSString`, `NSData` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd-MMM-yy HH:mm a"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
return dateString;
```

Hope this helps.